# Commit based view of Jenkins builds

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-api

I would like to be able to present a view of Jenkins builds similar to the [buildbot console](http://buildbot.buildbot.net/console) view. With Jenkins out of the box, there appears to be really no good way to associate a commit with a build. You have to access the specific built to determine what commit it was building.

I would like to be able to show status on what commits have been tested in a particular branch, so we know if a commit was skipped or if the latest commit has not yet been tested.

I tried using the Jenkins API for this, but I found that I could only see the SHA1 hash for a git commit via the build itself, i.e. via `http://server/job/job-name/388/api/json`. So, the only way I can see to take a commit and find builds for it is to iterate through every build in a job and retrieve its associated build info. This is certainly not going to be efficient and fast. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: What does `http://<jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/changes` say?

Comment: That url has no associated api, and doesn't associate commits with builds. I assume I'll need to add support for this task to Jenkins, but I've left this question open until that happens.

Answer (score 5):

Imperfect Answer: put the "revision number" you care about in **the package name** of all related artifacts, and use the "fingerprint" feature.

For example: my "product package" artifacts have a revision number, and if I carried that through to the "test package" artifact (which includes the unpacked product artifact) you would be able to track that revision number via the "artifact/fingerprint" feature, and show which test jobs used it. Below, you can't tell with a single click which test used which "commit."

[image: prod_fingerprint]
[image]